# Find and Replace for a string in Notepad++ using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this string:

```
MFRR_PRFX_NM (Manufacturer Prefix Name) VARCHAR(1024) NULL
```

I want to replace the above line with the below string.

```
cast(NULL as VARCHAR(1024)) as MFRR_PRFX_NM
```

I had tried using regular expression but was not able to sort this out.

Comment: Why do you need regex for this? As far as I can see, both strings are constant values. Why don't you use simple "Replace"?

Comment: I was not able to do it through the simple replace.Kindly share the code and steps if you are able to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

Find what: `(\w+)?.+?(VARCHAR.+) NULL`
Replace with: `cast\(NULL as $2\) as $1`

Don't forget to escape the parenthesis in the replacement part!

Comment: thnks a lot it worked with minor chnges for my code :)